# How to renew view on tab in tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, reloaddata

I have `UITabBarController` with two tabs.
Each tabs have `UITableViewController` which view data from database.

When I change data and switch tab view doesn't change.
When I back and switch tab again, view is ok!

How can I renew view programmatically?

Comment: Have you tried calling `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear:`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `<tableview>.reloadData()`. That will tell the table view to get the new count and fetch the displayed rows once again.

Comment: In what place should I do it?
I change data in one tab and see to another.

Comment: In the place where you modify the data itself. Where "When I change data" happens.

Answer (score 3):

Need to fetch data in viewWillAppear, don't in viewDidLoad.
Thank you Matthias Bauch!